# ASP.NET Core Webapi startup url - Docker-Compose vs. Docker build

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, kubernetes, docker-compose

I am encountering an interesting difference in startup behaviour when running a simple net6.0 web api built with docker-compose in comparison to being built with docker. The application itself runs in a kubernetes cluster.

**Environment**

Minikube v1.26.1

Docker Desktop v4.12

Docker Compose v2.10.2

**Building with docker-compose**

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"
services:

  web.api:
   build:
      context: ./../
      dockerfile: ./web.API/Dockerfile
```

The context is set to the parent directory due to some files needed there.

Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-alpine AS build 
WORKDIR /src

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80

COPY Directory.Build.props ./Directory.Build.props
COPY .editorconfig ./.editorconfig
COPY ["webapi/web.API", "web.API/"]
RUN dotnet build "web.API/web.API.csproj" -c Release --self-contained true --runtime alpine-x64

RUN dotnet publish "webapi/web.API.csproj"  -c Release -o /app/publish \
    --no-restore \
    --runtime alpine-x64 \
    --self-contained true \
    /p:PublishSingleFile=true

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime-deps:6.0-alpine
WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

COPY --from=build /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["./web.API"]
```

This results in the app starting up within the kubernetes cluster with the following logs:

> Now listening on: http://[::]:80

**Building with docker build**

Using the same Dockerfile mentioned earlier with the same build context you can see in the docker-compose.yml, a deployment to k8s results in the following log:

> Now listening on: http://localhost:5000

**Running the image locally**

Running the exact same image from the k8s cluster locally however results in

> Now listening on: http://[::]:80

**Already tried**

As suggested in many posts, I tried setting the environment variable ASPNETCORE_URLS via Dockerfile or k8s deployment.yml- neither of which had an impact on the startup url.

I can't seem to figure out why there is a difference between those 2 ways of building an image.

**Update**

The only thing that seems to work is to add

```
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(option =>{
    option.ListenAnyIP(80);
});
```

to the Program.cs.

Still not sure about the reason behind the behaviour though.

Comment: is that the whole docker-compose.yml? No hidden overrides that you are omitting like a docker-compose.debug.yml? Do you pass the ASPNETCORE_URLS env var at some point?

Comment: Why do you want to solve this issue? How is the difference effecting your app?

Comment: @Marco yes, this is the whole docker-compose.yml, no overrides.

Comment: @YaronIdan for once docker-compose is literally not necessary in this case. Building and deploying it through docker in a pipeline makes more sense. But the app is not accessible in k8s when listening to http://localhost:5000 even with correct service and container configuration

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

- I assume that the container already running and working on `port 80` `(docker run)` is stopped before attempting to run `docker-compose`?
- Environment variables can be used in `docker-compose.yml` file
- Ports most likely need to be exposed correctly, which from the `Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml` seems like it is not?

#### Environment Variables

First off, before the environmental `ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80` is going to be of any use, your `docker-compose` instance does not define which ports to use, your `docker-compose` (if trimmed) does not show any ports.

- Perhaps because the ports aren't exposed, this means the environmental tries to connect to `80`, which fails **(already in use/not exposed)** and then fails, and somehow connects on `5000`.
- Alternatively, more likely: it does not really not _see your `ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS`

You can try environment variables directly in your `docker-compose` file:

```
my-service:
  image: ${IMAGE_NAME}
  environment:
    MY_SECRET_KEY: ${MY_SECRET_KEY}
```

#### Publishing ports

In `docker-compose` file you need this, to **publish** ports:

```
   ports:
    - "80"
    - "443"

... or
   ports:
    - "80:80"  // "host-port:container-port"
    - "443:1234"
```

##### Additional information

> The keyword `EXPOSE\expose` in `Dockerfile/docker-compose.yml` is just informative (comments in a sense), functionally it does not process anything. A port need to be exposed (published) to be used.

So, those `EXPOSE 443 & 80` is not telling Docker to use it, perhaps you are running your container for example like this:

This **exposes** port 80 for it to be available.

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:80:80/tcp image command
```

In short, use `ports` keyword in `docker-compose.yml`.

#### EDIT:

I read your comment above:

> But the app is not accessible in k8s when listening to localhost:5000 even with correct service and container configuration

This indicates what I am trying to say regarding the ports being **published or not**. Your port 5000 is also not exposed because nothing in your configuration shows that is the case.

Comment: You misunderstood the issues - with docker-compose it is running just fine on port 80 without having to specify it. It's not about exposing ports from the container, its about what port the application within the container choses to listen to.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood, but I tried to answer to answer both environment variables and exposing ports in that case.